# Ball Game : Project

Tags: c, opengl

I'm working on a project where a ball will have random motion, the score displayed on top left corner and timer function of 1 min on top right corner. 
The purpose is that player will click on the ball and score will be incremented by one and the speed of the ball will increase. 
Till now I have made random motion, score displayed but I'm not able to calculate the position of the ball as in when the cursor goes over the ball then the score needs to be displayed otherwise not. So help me in detecting mouse over the moving ball. Here is my code :

```
    #include<GL/glut.h> 
#include<math.h> 
#include<stdbool.h> 
#include<stdio.h> 
#define PI 3.14159265f 


GLfloat ballRadius = 0.2; 
GLfloat ballX = 0.0f; 
GLfloat ballY = 0.0f; 
GLfloat ballXMax,ballXMin,ballYMax,ballYMin; 
GLfloat xSpeed = 0.02f; 
GLfloat ySpeed = 0.007f; 
int refreshMills = 30; 
int x1,xa,ya; 
int score = 0; 
int last_mx = 0, last_my = 0, cur_mx = 0, cur_my = 0; 
int arcball_on = false; 
int posx = -1,posy=0,posz=1; 
char *string; 
GLdouble clipAreaXLeft,clipAreaXRight,clipAreaYBottom,clipA reaYTop; 




void color() 
{ 
     if(score<=5) 
          glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); 
     else 
          glColor3ub( rand()%250, rand()%250, rand()%250 ); 
}    
void balldisp() 
{ 
    glTranslatef(ballX,ballY,0.0f); 
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN); 
    color(); 
    glVertex2f(0.0f,0.0f); 
    int numSegments = 100; 

    GLfloat angle; 
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<=numSegments;i++) 
    { 
         angle = i*2.0f*PI/numSegments; 
         glVertex2f(cos(angle)*ballRadius,sin(angle)*ballRa dius); 
    } 
    glEnd(); 

    ballX += xSpeed; 
    ballY += ySpeed; 

   if(ballX > ballXMax) 
   {
        xa=ballX; 
        ballX = ballXMax; 
        xSpeed = -xSpeed; 

   } 
   else if(ballX < ballXMin) 
   { 
        xa=ballX; 
        ballX = ballXMin; 
        xSpeed = -xSpeed; 

    } 
   if(ballY > ballYMax) 
   { 
        ya=ballY; 
        ballY = ballYMax; 
        ySpeed = -ySpeed; 

   } 
   else if(ballY < ballYMin) 
   { 
        ya=ballY; 
        ballY = ballYMin; 
        ySpeed = -ySpeed; 

    } 
} 

void scoredisp() 
{ 
    int z,j=0,k=0; 
    z=score; 
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); 
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glRasterPos2f(-1,1 ); 
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'S'); 
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'C'); 
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'O'); 
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'R'); 
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,'E'); 
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,' '); 
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,':'); 

    while(z > 9) 
    { 
        k = z % 10; 
        glRasterPos2f (-0.58,1); 
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,48+ k); 
        z /= 10; 
        glRasterPos2f(-0.62,1); 
     } 
     glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,48+ z); 
} 

void display() 
{ 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    balldisp(); 
    scoredisp(); 
    glFlush(); 
} 
void onMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) /// I want help here to detect mouse over the ball 
{ 



    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) 
    { 
        arcball_on = true; 
        cur_mx = x; 
        cur_my = y; 

    } 
    else 
    { 
        arcball_on = false; 
        if(cur_mx==x && cur_my==y) 
        { 
            score=score+1; 
        } 
        printf("%d",score); 
    } 



//return score; 

// xSpeed=xSpeed+0.02; 
// ySpeed=ySpeed+0.002; 
} 
void onMotion(int x, int y) 
{ 
    if (arcball_on)
    { 
        cur_mx = x; 
        cur_my = y; 
        printf("%d",cur_mx);
    } 
} 


void reshape(GLsizei width,GLsizei height) 
{ 
    if(height ==0) height = 1; 
        GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height; 
        glViewport(0,0,width,height); 
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
        glLoadIdentity(); 
    if(width >=height) 
    { 
        clipAreaXLeft = -1.0 * aspect; 
        clipAreaXRight = 1.0 * aspect; 
        clipAreaYBottom = -1.0; 
        clipAreaYTop = 1.0; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        clipAreaXLeft = -1.0; 
        clipAreaXRight = 1.0 ; 
        clipAreaYBottom = -1.0 / aspect; 
        clipAreaYTop = 1.0/ aspect; 
    } 
    gluOrtho2D(clipAreaXLeft,clipAreaXRight,clipAreaYB ottom,clipAreaYTop+0.10); 
    ballXMin = clipAreaXLeft + ballRadius; 
    ballXMax = clipAreaXRight - ballRadius; 
    ballYMin = clipAreaYBottom + ballRadius; 
    ballYMax = clipAreaYTop - ballRadius; 
} 

void Timer(int value) 
{ 
    glutPostRedisplay(); 
    glutTimerFunc(refreshMills,Timer,5); 
} 

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) 
{ 
    glutInit(&argc,argv); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB); 
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500); 
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100); 
    glutCreateWindow("Bouncing Ball"); 
    glutMouseFunc(onMouse); 
    glutMotionFunc(onMotion); 
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape); 
    glutPostRedisplay(); 
    glutTimerFunc(0,Timer,0); 
    glutMainLoop(); 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the distance formula to conclude whether the mouse is touching the ball.

1. Convert the click location from window coordinates to world coordinates.
2. Calculate the distance between the center of the ball and the mouse.
3. If the distance is less than the balls radius, the mouse is touching.

**Converting mouse position from window to world coordinates**

Since you have a fixed camera position and a predefined window size, you could do this but it isn't very versatile.

```
void windowToWorld(int windowX, int windowY, GLdouble *worldX, GLdouble *worldY){
    int x = windowX - 500 / 2;
    int y = windowY - 500 / 2;

    *worldX = (double)x / 250.0;
    *worldY = -(double)y / 250.0;
}
```

The more general way to do this is using gluUnProject, see here [NeHe Productions](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/using_gluunproject/16013/)

```
void windowToWorld(int windowX, int windowY, GLdouble *worldX, GLdouble *worldY){
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble modelview[16];
    GLdouble projection[16];
    GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
    GLdouble posZ;

    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    winX = (GLfloat)windowX;
    winY = (GLfloat)viewport[3] - (float)windowY;
    glReadPixels(windowX, (int)winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);

    gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, worldX, worldY, &posZ);
}
```

**Testing is ball is clicked**
This part is very simple using the distance formula.

```
bool isMouseOverBall(float worldClickX, float worldClickY, float ballX, float ballY)
{
    float distance = sqrt(pow(worldClickX - ballX, 2.0f) + pow(worldClickY - ballY, 2.0f));
    return distance < ballRadius;
}
```

**Finally**
you can find out whether the ball is clicked like this.

```
    GLdouble worldClickX, worldClickY;
    bool clicked;
    windowToWorld(x, y, &worldClickX, &worldClickY);
    clicked = isMouseOverBall(ballX, ballY, worldClickX, worldClickY);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks nkarasch can u please implement in my code and show,, im running out of time.. im trying but it is not happing

Comment: Sir i'm doing it in C so call by address in worldToWindow wont work. What is the alternative

Comment: Sorry, I didn't consider the differences between C and C++ when passing by reference. I've edited it so it should be working in C now.

Comment: Also, in the code you pasted below if ((worldClickX == 0 && worldClickY == 0)) will basically never be true. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with that but you almost never want to compare floating point values with ==. You have the boolean "clicked" that says whether the ball has been clicked, use that.

Comment: Thanks for helping... my project almost done..since yesterday night i was trying on this